# How to quickly lock the screen?

Tags: lock-screens

If you leave the android phone idle it will lock the screen, so you need draw lines in the dots to unlock it.

But I need quickly lock the phone when I will put in my bag, by example. Basic phones I simply hold the # or * button and the keys will lock.

How do I do to get this in android phones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press the power button on the device. All phones should have them and they are usually the buttons that lock the screen as well. If you happen to not have a lock button you can change how quickly Android will lock the screen on idle in settings. The way to change this varies from different flavors of Android.